# Which is better enabling indexing on RDBMS or Lucene Indexing

Tags: database, performance, indexing, lucene

I have an application which uses traditional Database for all of its data , i need to develop a search functionality, i did small prototype with lucene and results are gr8 , now the bigger question arises , for each of users add/delete/update operations i need to update db and the Lucene index too ,  will I get similar search performance if i just enable indexing on few fields in traditional db instead of moving to Lucene ? is it worth the effort ?.

Comment: Please check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553055/best-full-text-search-for-mysql and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119994/should-an-index-be-optimised-after-incremental-indexes-in-lucene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on the size of the corpus and on the type and frequency of updates.

A separated full-text search solution like lucene gives you much more flexibility when tweaking relevance, and by decoupling the updates of the rdbm and the full-text index gives you more options when trying to optimize performance.

If your never played with Lucene, I would greatly recommend you to use some more high-level solution, like Solr (or websolr), Sphinx, ElasticSearch or IndexTank. Lucene is very low level.